# Trigger Airflow DAG in another environment

Tags: airflow

I am running Airflow on one server. Within my DAGs and Tasks, there are cases in which I need to trigger DAGs which are maintained in a different Airflow installation on another server.

Is there a AirflowOperator similar to operators such as a DatabricksRunNowOperator? I checked already https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/packages-ref.html. I have not found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run) and trigger a DAG run. The [`SimpleHttpOperator`](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/http/modules/simplehttpoperator) can help with that out of the box in Airflow, using the [`HttpHook`](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/http/modules/httphook) inside a [`PythonOperator`](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/pythonoperator), or a TaskFlow function with a callable that you write yourself, etc.

The main takeaway is the Airflow REST API can help here and you can send a `POST` request in a few different ways however you are comfortable doing so.